# How to append value from a tkinter entry to list without apostophe

Tags: python, tkinter, append, tkinter-entry

I'm very new to programming and python as a whole, and there is probably an easy solution to my problem that I havn't found from my googling.

So, the problem lies at the definition of `Spared_list`. When I get the values from my Entry `spared` and put them into my list, each one of them gets saved with an apostroph around them. This is a problem later on in the program when I want to check if the value of `Count_up` exists in the list.

```
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

sparedlist=[]

def Spared_list():
    print("reached spared list")
    sparedlist.append(spared.get())
    print(sparedlist)

def execute():
    Count_up=0
    while Count_up < 1000:
        if Count_up in sparedlist:
            Count_up=Count_up+1
            print("HI")
        else:
            print("VKSK",Count_up," shut down",sep='')
            Count_up = Count_up+1
Chaos = tk.Tk()
Chaos.title("remote shutdown")
tk.Label(Chaos, text="Enter number of spared device(s) (ex:123, if device=VKSK123)").pack()
spared = tk.Entry(Chaos)
spared.pack()
tk.Button(Chaos, text="add", activebackground="Green", command=Spared_list).pack()
tk.Button(Chaos, text="execute", background="Red", command=execute).pack()
```

I know that this probably isn't the right way to code and use variables but I just reacently started out.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a problem later on in the program when I want to check if the value of Count_up exists in the list.

Your `sparedlist` contains **strings**, while your `Count_up` is an **integer**. If you wish to check if an integer is contained into a list of strings, you must first convert that integer into a string. E.g.

```
if str(Count_up) in sparedlist:
    ....
```

Or, convert your strings into integer as you add them to your list:

```
    sparedlist.append(int(spared.get()))
```